# Correct generic types for adding objects to lists in a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a series of shapes (`SVGShape`) and wish to add them to lists using a single method (which will carry out more logic). The code for adding `SVGCircle` works but is repetitive.  The code for `SVGEllipse` represents what I wish to do, so that there is a single method which is agnostic of which type it is passed, but fails to compile. The general type is (I think) `List<? extends SVGShape>` but this forbids addition of elements (at compile-time). 
Is what I am trying to do possible or does it needs rewriting?

```
// SVGCircle extends SVGShape
// SVGEllipse extends SVGShape
// List<SVGEllipse> ellipseList;
// List<SVGCircle> circleList;
for (SVGShape shape : shapeList) {
    if (shape instanceof SVGCircle) {
        SVGCircle circle = (SVGCircle) shape; // this compiles and works
        circleList.add(circle);
        circle.setId("circle"+circleList.size());
    } else if (shape instanceof SVGEllipse) {
        SVGEllipse ellipse = (SVGEllipse) shape;
        addToListAndSetId(ellipseList, ellipse); // fails to compile
    }
}
private void addToListAndSetId(List<SVGShape> shapeList, SVGShape shape) {
    shapeList.add(shape);
    // more logic here
    shape.setId(shape.getLocalName().toLowerCase() + shapeList.size());
}
```

NOTE: 2 answers have now given the correct form of the method. For completeness here is the revised calling syntax:

```
if (shape instanceof SVGCircle) {
    addToListAndSetId(circleList, (SVGCircle) shape);
} else if (shape instanceof SVGEllipse) {
    addToListAndSetId(ellipseList, (SVGEllipse) shape);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the signature of your method to `void addToListAndSetId(List<? extends SVGShape>, SVGShape shape)`, it doesn't allow additions to the `List`, since nothing is stopping you from passing to the method a `List<SVGEllipse>` with a `SVGRectangle` (which you shouldn't be able to add to that `List`).

You can add a generic type parameter to your method:

```
private <T extends SVGShape> void addToListAndSetId(List<T> shapeList, T shape) {
    shapeList.add(shape);
    // more logic here
    shape.setId(shape.getLocalName().toLowerCase() + shapeList.size());
}
```

This way if the first argument is a `List<SVGEllipse>`, the second argument must be a `SVGEllipse`, which can be safely added to that list.

Comment: Now it becomes clear - `T` binds the arguments together!

Comment: This code works. I have added the revised calling procedure to the question as NOTE

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use generics.

```
private <T extends SVGShape> void addToListAndSetId(List<T> shapeList, T shape) {
    shapeList.add(shape); // more logic here    
    shape.setId(shape.getLocalName().toLowerCase() + shapeList.size());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Better way to force type matching in function would be to use `T extends SVGShape` as mentioned by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) in his answer, so function `<T extends SVGShape> void addToListAndSetId2(List<T> list, T shape)` is a better solution because mismatched arguments will not compile (as required):

```
//List<SVGEclipse> eclipses;
//SVGCircle circle;

addToListAndSetId2(eclipses, circle); // this will not compile as required


//List<SVGShape> eclipses;
//SVGCircle circle;

addToListAndSetId(eclipses, circle); // this will compile although should NOT
```

---- before edit:

You should create lists of generic type instead of 
`List<SVGCircle>, List<SVGEclipse>` use the generic class or interface like `List<SVGShape> or List<ISVGShape>`.

Below is the code snippet that works at compile time. I have also listed the other classes which I have assumed based on your question details:

```
public static void main(String []args) {

        List<SVGShape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
        // cirlce list of generic type
        List<SVGShape> circleList = new ArrayList<>();
        // eclipse list fof generic type
        List<SVGShape> ecliplseList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(SVGShape shape: shapes) {
            if(shape instanceof SVGCircle) {
                SVGCircle svgCircle = (SVGCircle) shape;
                svgCircle.setId("some-id");
                circleList.add(svgCircle);
                addToListAndSetId(circleList, svgCircle);
            } else if(shape instanceof  SVGEcliplse){
                SVGEcliplse ecliplse = (SVGEcliplse) shape;
                ecliplseList.add(ecliplse);
                addToListAndSetId(ecliplseList, ecliplse);
            }
        }
    }

    // This does not force both params to be of same type 
    public static void addToListAndSetId(List<SVGShape> shapeList, SVGShape shape) {
        shapeList.add(shape);
        if(shape instanceof SVGCircle) {
              shape.setId("some-circle-id");
        } else if(shape instanceof  SVGEcliplse) {
              shape.setId("some-eclipse-id");
        }
    }

    // This DOES force both params (shapelist type and shape type) to be of same type 
    public <T extends SVGShape> void addToListAndSetId2(List<T> shapeList, T shape) {
        shapeList.add(shape);
        shape.setId("some-id");
    }


public class SVGCircle extends SVGShape {
}

public class SVGEcliplse extends SVGShape {
}

public class SVGShape implements ISVGShape {
    public void setId(String id) {
        // some logic
    }
}

public interface ISVGShape {
}
```

Comment: I think this makes it less clear and less maintainable. For each new type and list we have to edit the method, while the current solution has a universal method and a single line call.

(BTW you write `SVGEcliplse` and this will confuse readers as I wrote `SVGEllipse`)

Comment: Also `List<SVGShape>` does not prevent me adding first a circle and then a rect.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust agree. added an edit to my answer